# C++ Intellisense with descriptions

Tags: c++, intellisense

Hello is there some IDE or some plugin or any other way that provides a C# Like intellisense for C++ ? 
like not just only the parameters & overloads but also a small description eg : cout : outputs message to ... ;; just like in C#.

& thanks !

Comment: Does nothing such as this http://i30.tinypic.com/29x6lo4.png exists ? Did no one in all these years try to comment the C++ Libraries in order make it work with VS's intellisense ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mohammad already answered, Visual Studio already has nice Intellisense capabilities for C++.

If it isn't good enough for you, you can add some plug-ins for VS that will improve the Intellisense (and the whole "coding experience").

A good plugin that can help you is **Visual Assist X** which can be found at **wholetomato.com**

Specifically, You can check out its Intellisense capabilities at http://www.wholetomato.com/products/featureIntellisense.asp

You should also check out another alternative: **Eclipse CDT**

Hope it helps...

Tal.

Answer (score 9):

There is apparently [a mechanism for displaying such information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0we08bk.aspx), but it requires code to be documented with comments.  Your standard headers (containing cout, etc) may or may not already have such comments in them.

From MSDN:

> IntelliSense determines which comment to display in the Members list by where it appears in the code:
>
> 1: IntelliSense first displays end-of-line comments in the declaration. For example:
>
> ```
> void MyFunction();   //EOL declaration comments
> ```
>
> 2: If IntelliSense does not find the previous type of comment, it displays comments that appear directly above the declaration with no blank lines in between. For example:
>
> ```
> //Before declaration comments   
> void MyFunction();
> ```
>
> 3: If the previous two types of comments are not found in the code, IntelliSense displays end-of-line comments in the definition. For example:
>
> ```
> int CMyAppDoc::MyVariable=2; // EOL definition comments
> ```
>
> 4: Finally, if none of the previous types of comments appear in the code, IntelliSense displays comments that appear directly above the definition with no blank lines in between. For example:
>
> ```
> //Before definition comments
> CMyAppDoc::MyFunction()  {
>     return; 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

By default Visual Studio will show you any comment you put above a method,... when you're using intellisense.
For example with this:

```
// Test doc
void test()
{
}
```

VS will show you "Test doc" when autocompletion window is open.